# Formatting a set of NSDecimalNumber values

Tags: cocoa-touch, math, formatting, nsdecimalnumber

I'm working on an app where I need to take several sets of numeric values (currently stored as `NSDecimalNumber`), and display them in columns. Each set will have approximately the same magnitude, but the magnitude of each set may change, and I won't know ahead of time what they are. So one might be values like (1.23, 2.3, 1.567), and another (1234.1, 2345, 1999.4).

In order to make the columns line up, and to know how much space I'll need, what I'd like to do is to figure out, for each set of numbers, the width of the format I'll need. In other words, the maximum number of integer places, and the maximum number of fractional places. For the examples above: 1 and 3 in the first case, 4 and 1 in the second.

Now, the [`NSDecimal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-BAJEJDDJ) representation would answer this directly, by combining the length of the mantissa and the value of the exponent. The problem is, the fields of that structure are explicitly private, and there doesn't appear to be any API to get the values of the mantissa and exponent out of it.

A workaround might be to convert each number to a string in the POSIX locale, and then measure its length and the position of the decimal point. But that seems like a very long way around.

I'm pretty sketchy on my C math, but I'd guess that there's some way to get this information by converting my decimal to a `double`, and then examining that (either will standard library functions or poking the bits) and doing some logs. I don't know how exactly, or whether I should be concerned about the conversion to a lossy representation.

Is there a more direct and/or more efficient way of deriving this information?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever particular technique you use, if you want it to be fully automatic you have to do some kind of prior iteration over all the numbers. And you're going to be displaying all the numbers as well. So converting them all to strings ahead of time and saving these strings, say in a parallel array, doesn't seem like the worst thing in the world, and you can measure the total length directly. To deal with decimal points lining up, calculate the maximum and minimum numbers during the conversion iteration. These two numbers will give you the maximum width of the integer part. If the minimum number is negative, remember to allocate space for the minus sign.